# How I change the default folder into a continuous deployment from a git-azure repository?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm working with a simple application in ASP.NET Core. The repository is on Azure Devops git and I deploy this into a App Service.
Under the Deployment Server I configurated Continuous Deployment (CI /CD) and It works, but the files are sent to wwwwroot of the server. Instead, I need them into /site/wwwroot/theFolderThatICreated.
I've searched DevOps git Pipelines/Releases, but do not understood where I configure this thing.

Resume: when I do a push to the master branch of my project, I want the content send to a folder under wwwroot of my app service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change anything, the pipeline will by default deploy your app to `wwwroot` folder.

1.To deploy to your created folder, you can either change the physical path in azure web portal:

[image]

2.Or you can use `VirtualApplication` input in [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to expand the path. If you enter `/FolderName` in VirtualApplication, then your application files will be deployed to `site\wwwroot\FolderName`.

Both two ways should work, hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, It works! But I think I will need the second approach, because I will deploy more than one project to the same App Service. So... All my projects will need a deploy task that configures the /foldername, right? What parameter you used to do this? Really...Many many thanks for the help! =)

Comment: Nevermind... The parameter is VirtualApplication (Duh!) So... It goes into my YAML file?

Comment: Hmm, yes the parameter is also `VirtualApplication` if you're using yaml.