# webjob deployment with azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

Trying to configure webjob deployment for azure webjob with azure devops using app service deploy task. when ever i try to deploy it's deploying to root folder instead of continuous / triggered folder. can someone please help me.

using .net/asp.net framework solution

below task using as default setting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qj2g.png)

Comment: Just checking in to see is there any update for this issue, feel free to let me know if the issue persists to block you :)

Answer (score 1):

> When ever i try to deploy it's deploying to root folder instead of
>   continuous / triggered folder.

Normally the default folder is `wwwroot` folder if you don't do any changes. And to control which folder the files will be deployed to we can use `Virtual Application` in your screenshot.

There's two `Virtual Application` can affect this deploy behavior: The `Virtual Application` setting in your Deploy task and the `Virtual applications and directories` in Azure Web portal. You can find some details about how they work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60501848/10910450).

You can easily control the folder to deploy to with the help of `Virtual Application`. Hope it helps :)